# ¿Los hijos en Flexbox pueden cambiar el width del padre?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

En mis `item1` meteré la imagen que me llegue de una videoconferencia, por lo que quiero que el ancho del `container1` y `container2` dependa del número de personas en la sala.

Me gustaría que `container1` hiciera estrecharse a `container2` si aparecen más `item1` y se recolocan en 2 columnas. ¿Es esto posible? ¿Hay otra solución?

```css
.main{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 400px;
        height:260px; 
        padding: 5px;
        justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        border:solid;
      }
.container1{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
        height: 100%;
        border:solid;
     }
.container2{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        border:solid;
        justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
     }
.item1{
        width: 100px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: blue;
        border-radius: 15px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        color:white;
        font-size:20px;
      }
       .item2{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 15px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        color:white;
        font-size:30px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="item1">.item1</div>
    <div class="item1">.item1</div>
    <div class="item1">.item1</div>
    <div class="item1">.item1</div>
 </div>

<div class="container2">
   <div class="item2">.item2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola monestina como estas?

Desde mi conocimiento de Flexbox un contenedor tiene definida a través de la propiedad width en css un ancho y este no se modifica automáticamente.

Observa en el código de ejemplo de (el hijo 2 que esta de color azul claro).

La única forma de cambiar el ancho de un elemento padre, es cuando no le defines un ancho con la propiedad de css width. Sino que el elemento padre adopta el ancho de los elementos hijo en pixeles o medidas que no sean porcentaje.

Observa en el código el ejemplo de (el hijo 1 que esta en color gris y sus elementos hijos en rojo)

Para hacer que el elemento padre crezca debes definir dentro de el la propiedad de flexbox siguiente:

```
flex-wrap:nowrap;
```

Para que los elemento hijo se organicen de forma lineal y no puedan colocarse uno debajo del otro.

Ahora, para hacerlo crecer los elementos hijos deben tener un ancho especificado en pixeles y mientras mas elementos agregas mas crecerá el ancho del elemento padre.

Si en el ejemplo de (el hijo 1  le agregas mas elementos `<p1>1</p>`) automáticamente crecerá el ancho del elemento padre (hijo 1) y achicara como tu quieres al elemento (hijo 2).

[image: Antes]

[image: Después de agregar mas hijos]

> Ojo: El elemento padre principal que esta en color naranja también tiene la propiedad

```
 flex-wrap:nowrap;
```

Que es la que permite achicar al contenedor (hijo 2)

```css
.flex-padre{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background:orange;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

.flex-hijo1{
  
  background:gray;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}

.flex-hijo2{
  width:30%;
  background:aquamarine;
}

.flex-hijo1 p{
  width:50px;
  background:red;
  margin:1% 1%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-padre">
      <p>Padre</p>
      <div class=flex-hijo1>
        <p>Hijo1</p>
         <p>1</p>
         <p>2</p>
         <p>1</p>
         <p>2</p>
         <p>1</p>
         <p>2</p>
         <p>2</p>
 <p>1</p>
         <p>2</p>
         <p>2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-hijo2">
        <p>Hijo2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Keysel:

Necesito tener el `wrap` para que los elementos me vayan apareciendo uno debajo de otro y cuando lleguen el límite inferior del flex salten a la segunda columna. Con este salto quisiera que el flex padre que los contiene se expanda y el otro flex padre de la derecha se contraiga... ahí está mi problema.